# ORA-01427 error , insert into all rows

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

My query keeps returning an ORA-01427 error, how to resolve it please:

I have 3 tables: T1 with (idA,B)columns, B type date
                 T2 with (idC,D)columns, D type varchar
                 T3 with (idE,F,G,....)columns, F type date, G type varchar, idE(DBsquences),F and G are Primary Key.

I want to insert into T3, data from T1 and T2

My query:

```
insert into T3 (F, G) values ((select B from T1 where max(B)), ( select D from T2));
```

I get: ORA-01427 error Single-row subquery returns more than one row.

How can i do this with cursor?

```
T1:

idA   B   
------------
1     date1      
2     date2  (the max date)     
3     date3 

T2:

idC    D    
----------
1     x       
2     y  
3     z
.     .
.     .
.     .
n     N

Result must be:

T3:

idE    F          G
-----------------------
1     date2       y
2     date2       z
.       .         .
.       .         .
.       .         .
.       .         .
n     date2       N
```

Comment: Everything is wrong here :) If you insert values from select, you don't need `values` key word, but you should use only 1 query. And it is not valid condition - `where max(B)`. You can't use group functions in `WHERE`, only `HAVING`. You should make a condition like `max(B) = someting`

Comment: Please, can you add information about the logic: why `T3.G` is y instead of x for `T3.ide` with value 1 .
 You dont need cursor, you have to use a simple query from T2 with T1 max date, then use the `insert into .. select`. Why dont you use a view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right:

```
INSERT INTO T3 (F, G)
SELECT  (select max(B) from T1), D
FROM T2
```

If you insert values from select, you don't need `values` key word, but you should use only 1 query. And it is not valid condition - `where max(B)`. You can't use group functions in `WHERE`, only `HAVING`. You should make a condition like `max(B) = something`. If you want to chose max value, you just use function max in `SELECT`

Comment: Thank you Tatiana, i understand the right way to insert data from table, not need to put VALUES